# Eclipse Subversion: Risks of the team project

Tags: svn

I develop some project with my team using svn. SVN is new for me, I have checked out the project and would like to try out the differents functionality of SVN (for example, team-> commit, update, revert.. etc)

My Question is: Is there any risk for the project the whole team is using? Can I do something wrong on the projct (for example changing/deleting files, which can not be undo)

Comment: First of all if you were using git instead of svn I could say 'click-away my friend, any thing git knows is on every developers computer' but with SVN you can do some nasty mess  i.e. since svn uses date tracked diffs, all mess can be sorted out but it can cost a lot of hairs and time. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is lot of points can be considered but that is the benefit of SVN that you can synchronize with your team and aware of changes asap. So I mean purpose of SVN is to get rid of those risks.
 Some points I can say so far:

- *You should have a reflex that you need to update your project in every opportunity
- *Make sure you are synchronized (keep in touch) with the team and you know who is working on what so you can get rid of editing conflicts
  and updating same code
- *If you get conflicts never change someone else code, if possible revert to latest changes and add your changes.
- *Make very clear comments, if you are working with ticket system consider ticket number
- *You can see entire history of SVN and changes on specified file. i.e. x person changed this code block on this date etc... so it gives
  you clear overview
- *You can compare any revision/commit with another commit. This also gives a clear overview and makes faster debugging progress.
- **When I delete a file first I update project to see if file has been pointed out from someone else in last minutes if not I am running
  application that agin make sure test cases has valid result and
  commiting my changes.

And with subversion: **everything can be undo**. That is the one the great benefit that you can rever to previous revisions.

***Iam not sure this question belongs to here but I have added my answer.*